# Looking for a Java CMS that allows custom modules in JSF

Tags: java, jsf, content-management-system

We currently develop our web apps in JSF 1.1 and looking to move to JSF 2.0 (Primefaces), but we'd also like to reuse CMS functionality and allow the business users to edit content and UI design elements. So rather than roll our own CMS we're looking for a good programmable Java CMS (Content Management System) that uses JSF. Doesn't have to open source, but not IBM prices. Something like [sitefinity](http://www.sitefinity.com/) for Java would be ideal.

Ideally we'd like to reuse our existing applications code and components, so if the CMS supported JSF modules/components/portlets that would be great. But none of the ones I've looked at seem to support JSF.

Looked briefly at Liferay, Spring Surf, Hippo CMS, Jease.

[Spring surf](http://www.springsource.org/extensions/se-surf) looks really promising but still incubator and the moment although no JSF. 
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Liferay http://www.liferay.com/

http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/1080821  JSF portlet development in liferay

Comment: Saw this today the Primefaces JSF component library and Liferay playing nice http://cagataycivici.wordpress.com/2011/02/02/primefaces-on-liferay/